# What is tool exists in AngularJS for template?

Tags: angularjs

For example, I have HTML code in variable JS:

```
var template = '<div>%name%</div>';
```

How easy to replcae `%name%` on text in template? What is tools provided in Angular JS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is simple interpolation - angular does this out of the box with two way data binding, for example, take the following:

```
<html ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div>Hello {{vm.name}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could have a script like this:

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])

.controller('ExampleController', function(){
  this.name = "World";
})
```

Which would print out "Hello World".

This is really basic though - if you're asking this question you definitely read more about angular before you attempt to create an application.

I would recommend the course at thinkster.

Comment: I can not use this way, because HTML in page generated by PHP, so I need create HTML template with data after add via `append()` to HTML page

Comment: @Alibabaev please take my advice and read more about angular. It's a single page web application framework - PHP should generate **one** HTML page which is pretty much just a shell, then angular will fill in the gaps with a router, views and directives. If you're frequently using `.append()`, you're frankly doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, what is way I must use in my case? Rebuild application from php to Angular JS? Or load data by AJAX in Angular?

Comment: Is possible to do: `<div ng-init="test = '<?=$notifications['social']?>'"></div>

{{test}} `

Comment: Yes, you need to rebuild the app entirely or load php-generated partials via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides possibilities to create HTML templates, **data binding**, loops, filters, ajax and you can extend everything you want with directives, you can create components to shrink you templates to be even smaller and concise. [Here you can find examples and also some documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates), AngularJS is very popular so it's easy to find resources.

Comment: Question is not about it, also I have not found nothing about replacing text in template HTML, only standart model data in Angular like as `{{data}}`